# Chop saw not square after alignment

Tags: miter-saw, saw-blade

I just got a new jointer and after aligning it I took a piece of white oak flooring and face planed then edge planed and the faces were nicely square with the edges but the ends were not. So I went over to the chop saw and took my nice edge against the fence and cut the ends and noticed the edge to end was slightly askew.

So I took my square and placed it against the fence and checked the blade and it was indeed slightly askew. I loosened the angle bracket and adjusted it until the 0 degree detent was exactly square against the blade and tightened back down.

[image: Blade is square to fence]

I took another piece of the flooring and chopped off one end and it was perfectly square with the edge.
[image: End cut square to edge]
[image: Measure end]

I flipped the board 180° and chopped off the other end. It also was perfectly square with the same edge.

[image: other end is square]
So now I have two 90° angles from that one edge.

I butted one of the 90° ends against the fence and cut the other edge which should be parallel to the other but it is not. In fact, it is skewed quite a bit and I can't understand how this is happening.
[image: not square end]

Comment: "I flipped the board 180 and chop off the other end" did you flip it end-to-end, keeping the finished side up, or did you _also_ turn it over so the finished side was down? i.e. did you rotate it horizontally around the vertical axis or did you rotate vertically it around the long horizontal axis?

Comment: The difference is that the first "flip" puts different edges against the fence while the second "flip" keeps the same edge against the fence. It's not entirely clear from your question which way. If it was the first way, that would account for it.

Comment: I flipped it end to end 180 keeping same edge against fence. The left side of the 2 measurement photos is the same edge that was against the fence. I am double checking the fence alignment now.

Comment: In your last pic, are you checking square against the edge that was trued up on the jointer and against the fence of the miter saw?

Comment: Yes, but I found the problem I think. The "good" square I was using, a Savage by Swanson, which I thought was my best is off! 86.7º in fact according to my digital angle meter. I measured it several times and then noticed it was slightly off.

Comment: Just shows to go ya, your measurements are only as accrurate as your measuring device. Headed to Woodpeckers for a good square.

Answer (score 6):

The square I was using as reference was not square. I measured it at 87.6º which would account for the inaccuracy. I found it by using the square against three other framing squares and they were all off. Then I looked at what I was using as three could not all be off the same amount!

Comment: Yikes! Check your tape measures before starting your next project, too. :D

Comment: Also, sounds like you've got an afternoon of rechecking _all_ your tools for square.

Comment: Nearly 3° off, yikes! Did you drop it recently or do you think it was always like that?

Comment: I picked up a tape measure (Milwaukee) a few months back and was having all kinds of trouble making things fit...until I discovered the marks were off by about 1/16" in just over two feet. I foolishly assumed that it was good, since it was a name brand, but comparing it to all the others I had showed it was garbage.

Comment: You can quickly check a square by marking 90 off a straight edge, then flipping the square over (same edge but the other side of the line) and drawing another 90. If they are the same line, you’re perfect.